# Random Numbers Printed Out of a Class instead of specific ones C++

Tags: c++

so here is my simple programm setting an object (sp) of the class (Spots) and although in the main function specific values are set, when executed I get random numbers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoLuR.png

What am I missing?

Comment: Please include your code in your question, not an external image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't initializing the member variables in your constructor. Your constructor should be

```
Spots(int weather_, bool treasure_, bool port_)
{
    weather = weather_;
    treasure = treasure_;
    port = port_;
}
```

Or if you prefer the [initialization list syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

```
Spots(int weather_, bool treasure_, bool port_)
: weather{weather_}, treasure{treasure_}, port{port_} {}
```

As you have currently written your constructor, the input arguments happen to have the same name as your member variables (which is a problem), but you basically pass them in, then do nothing with them, which leaves the member variables uninitialized.

Comment: Just a side note: Initialization lists also do "the right thing" if the constructor arguments have the same names as the member variables they are initializing.